# Dynamic search of returned MySQL data

Tags: python, mysql, forms, flask

How does one go about dynamically searching MySQL data? To be specific, I want to query a table, for example:

```
mysql> select * from points where LAT != 0.0
```

After that I want to query only the information returned from the previous query:

```
mysql> select LAT, LON, FILE from points where LAT > 30.457835
```

How do I query my previous result instead of searching the entire database each time?

What I'm trying to reach is integrating a dynamic search form in Flask where each field selected in the form narrows down your results displayed on the web page. It seems to me that this kind of thing happens all the time, for example in library databases, or even amazon for that matter. Does each new criteria that you add create an entire new search string to bang at the database, or can you store this info in memory temporarily and query against your previous result?

I can see how that would be problematic with monstrous databases, but my project will rarely ever hit a Gig in size.

If my question is off base here, please let me know so that I can rephrase. I ultimately will be working this through flask / python, but I felt I should understand how the MySQL piece worked first. A simple search form in flask and returning results is simple, but making it user friendly in a sensible way is escaping me right now.

Thanks.

Comment: You can put the results of the first query in a new table, and then query that. But I suspect most applications just add the new conditions to the old query, so it becomes `WHERE LAT != 0.0 AND LAT > 30.4` and they use that to query against the full table.

Comment: That was my suspicion too, but I can't seem to find any boiler plate style examples for using multiple search fields on a form with flask...or even just html for that matter. This is definitely a common thing, I just think the terminology I'm searching google and stack with doesn't really get the desired result. I basically want to make a form that lets users filter each column for different values. I use stuff like this all the time on spreadsheets of course as an example.

Comment: I don't know how you do it with Flask, but it's not very different from a form where you can have multiple conditions. The only difference is that some of the conditions are saved from the earlier form that you're adding to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries:

```
select sq.LAT, sq.LON, sq.FILE 
from (select * from points where LAT != 0.0) as sq
where sq.LAT > 30.457835
```

Comment: ,Would you mind expanding on this a little? Would this give me the ability to   handle the case where users selected no search criteria for a given column? Say for example, I render all the points where LAT > 1, then they decide to change and would like to render all the points where LAT > 5...(for whatever weird reason)? How would I break this up into incremental statements that may or may not be actually refining the search?

Comment: @KennyPowers This is only for when they're requesting a refinement of the original results. If they're replacing the old criteria rather than refining it, you start fresh.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are asking. You can always change the query, run multiple subqueries within a query, or run multiple queries and join them. There is really a lot you can do to manipulate data with SQL. But like James said below, in this particular case it is really pointless to check if `LAT != 0` if you already checking if `LAT > 30`. I thought you just wanted to understand the general principles of subquerying

Comment: Yes, understood. So, that was a bad example. What I really mean is would be the following: select * from points where LAT > 1
Then they refine that with:
where LON > 1 
as well. The real mind warp to me right now, is constructing the string to pass to mysql regardless of whether the forms have been selected or not. A user could want to refine 1 of say 5 columns, or all of them, one at a time.

Comment: It's clear I need to go read on sq's. Wasn't aware of this in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options here:

Firstly (and not so great a solution) is to select from the query results:

```
select * from (
 select LAT, LON, FILE from points where LAT > 30.457835
)
 where LAT != 0.0;
```

Second (much more efficient) is to combine the search criteria into a single query:

```
select LAT, LON, FILE from points where LAT > 30.457835 and  LAT != 0.0;
```

However in you example this would be rather pointless as anything greater than 30.457835 will definitely be not equal to zero.

A third ( and drastically inefficient ) option would be to write the results of the first query to a temporary table, then query the temporary table. The SQL for this is somewhat complex and I would recommend it only if you are running several queries against the resulting  temporary table.

Comment: The problem with a temporary table is that it will be deleted when the MySQL session closes, which normally happens when the first page returns its results.

Comment: So the first page would have to write its results to a permanent table, then when you add additional criteria on the second page, it will query that permanent table. You'll need a periodic job to clean up all these tables.

Comment: @Bamar -- I agree that a temporary table is problematic and only of use in very particular circumstances -- but it a a valid option.

Comment: I guess you're suggesting that the second page would re-do the query from the previous search, put its results in the temp table, and then immediately query the temp table.